# COALESCE vs OR condition for JOIN (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, coalesce

I have `Event` table

```
TABLE Event(
EventId [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
EventSource1Id [int] NULL,
EventSource2Id [int] NULL
)
```

that contains info about events from different sources
where one of the event sources can be null

```
TABLE EventSource1(
Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name [nvarchar](50) NULL,
VenueId [int] NOT NULL
)
```

and

```
TABLE EventSource2(
Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name [nvarchar](50) NULL,
VenueId [int] NOT NULL
)

TABLE Venue(
Id [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
TimeZone [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)
```

I'd like to create view, but I'm not sure what is the best way to use: `coalesce` vs `OR condition` for `JOIN`

First option:

```
SELECT 
ev.[Id] AS 'Id',
ven.[Id] AS 'VenueId'
FROM Event ev
LEFT JOIN EventSource1 source1 ON source1.[Id] = ev.EventSource1Id
LEFT JOIN EventSource2 source1 ON source2.[Id] = ev.EventSource2Id
LEFT JOIN Venue AS ven ON ven.[Id] = source1.[VenueId] OR v.[Id] = source2.[VenueId]
```

Second option:

```
SELECT 
ev.[Id] AS 'Id',
ven.[Id] AS 'VenueId'
FROM Event ev
LEFT JOIN EventSource1 source1 ON source1.[Id] = ev.EventSource1Id
LEFT JOIN EventSource2 source1 ON source2.[Id] = ev.EventSource2Id
LEFT JOIN Venue AS ven ON ven.[Id] = COALESCE(source1.[Id], source2.[Id])
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: use the execution plan to look at what would be best

Comment: don't forget to put proper index too

Comment: Aside: Two separate event source tables with identical schemas sitting between events and venues looks suspicious. Two (nullable) event source id's for each event. Wouldn't it make more sense to have tables for `Events`, `EventSources`, `Event_EventSources` and `Venues`? You could add an `EventSourceType` to `EventSources` if you need to distinguish between (presently) two types of event sources and you could restrict the `Event_EventSources` table to not allow more than two event sources for any given event.

Comment: Those two are not equivalent. Not null values of `source1.Id` will prevent it from ever looking at `source2`. That may work with the data you have but in general it's not true. I know you said "one of them can be null" but that's not the same as "one of them is always null".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The COALESCE will typically yield a better query plan.  You should test with your data.